# How to modify source code and deploy Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am modifying the source code of the `kubelet`.
For compiling, I can do `make quick-release`. And I can get the executable `kubelet` from the `_output`

Then I replace the original `/usr/bin/kubelet` with the new executable, but when I run `kubeadm init`, it gives me the error message:

`[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: couldn't get kubelet version: Unable to parse output from Kubelet: "Kubernetes v0.0.0-master+$Format:%h$"`

I believe there must be a standard way to compile and deploy Kubernetes. My googled resource are mostly about developing application on Kubernetes. Can anyone give me a guide or give some keywords so I can google on my own?

Thanks

--

Update

I replaced the `kubelet` in `minikube` env.

And I got the permission error.

`W0613 16:34:55.917805   26616 status_manager.go:496] Failed to update status for pod "kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system(5ff9a836-6f27-11e8-8667-080027c176b2)": failed to patch status "{\"status\":{\"$setElementOrder/conditions\":[{\"type\":\"Initialized\"},{\"type\":\"Ready\"},{\"type\":\"PodScheduled\"}],\"conditions\":[{\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2018-06-13T16:34:51Z\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"Ready\"}]}}" for pod "kube-system"/"kube-apiserver-minikube": pods "kube-apiserver-minikube" is forbidden: User "system:node:minikube" cannot patch pods/status in the namespace "kube-system"`

--

Update again

I found that it's the version inconsistent problem.
Once I checkout the same version of the Kubernete in minikube `git checkout v1.10.0`, then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io/kubernetes
make clean
# use the version you used, like v1.9.2-123
git tag v1.x.x-xxxx
make kubelet
# should show the above tag
_output/bin/kubelet --version
```

If you just modified source code of a single component, you doesn't need to `make quick-release`, just `make <componenet_name>` (for example, `make kubelet`,`make kube-proxy`...). And you just need to tag once (the tag should be there after new changes made to the source code).

Comment: thanks. How about the deployment, just copy the `kubelet` to `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: @chinuy Yes if it needs to be in the `PATH`. It should work following the Kubeadm docs. Any other errors occured?